# Saving locations using Google Maps without violating T&Cs

Tags: web-services, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I am currently working on an app (not live yet) that will allow users to create projects and set the location of each.

I originally added an autocomplete field that worked with the Google maps lookup to help the user type in the location and also it would find the latitude and longitude of the place/location and show it on a map.

At this point I was saving the location, latitude and longitude to database fields.

This made the user experience quite straight forward.

However, I now think this idea of storing the autocompleted location violates 10.1.3 of [Google Maps T&Cs](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms).

I need to include the locations in my list page and Google allows short term caching for performance purposes but surely that would mean I would need to update the cache or something for each entry at least every 30 days which isn't really an option.

This would also mean that the location data belongs to Google which limits any future use of this data (an API on my site for instance).

I wondered if it would be an option to use [openstreetmap data](http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/) to get the full location (although I'm not sure if it can be used to provide an autocomplete facility) and then pass that to the google maps lookup so that the location provided by the openstreetmap autocomplete with looser restrictions can be saved to the database. However, even if that was all possible it could be confusing for the user if the openstreetmap autocomplete failed to find a location/place that exists on google or it was labelled differently.

I'm not sure if that's an option or not.

I am currently tending towards a plain text box with an example location shown alongside it so the user can see the extent that the location needs to be typed (ie a full address) so that when it is used to lookup the location via Google it will bring back the correct latitude and longitude but will also be informative to users when they see it on the list page.

This does mean that the location field content is ok to store in the database then but it puts more reliance on the user typing the address in correctly and if they don't type it in properly the auto lookup may fail to locate it and/or it may not be viewer-friendly on the list page.

Can anyone offer any better ways that I could help users to type in an accurate location (which could be a place with address or just an address) so that it doesn't violate the terms and conditions and allows my site to have ownership of the location?

Thanks